# ssh does not read from ssh config

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-config

I have an ssh configuration file as follows

```
Host default
   User git
   Hostname github.com
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host work
   User git
   Hostname github.com
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work

Host para
   User git
   Hostname github.com
   IdentityFile /home/dev/.ssh/para
```

I do have access for all the github repos and have added public keys

But when I tried to do the following

```
ssh -T git@default
ssh -T git@para
ssh -T git@work
```

It throws an error

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname: Name or service not known
```

I am using ubuntu 20.04 in VMware player

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Where is your ssh configuration file located?

Comment: Given that ssh isn't showing the failing host name, it's possible that ssh itself is working fine, and that `github.com` cannot be resolved, due to a *resolver* setup issue. What happens if you use `ssh -T git@github.com -i /home/dev/.ssh/para` for instance? That would point you to whether it's ssh not reading `~/.ssh/config`, or whether it's a more general name-resolution issue.

Comment: Ubuntu 20 doesn't exist. Do you mean 20.04? There's also 20.10 and Core 20.

Comment: Adding debugging info at level 1 `-v` or level 2 `-vv` will give you more information.  The `-G` flag "Causes ssh to print its configuration after evaluating Host and Match blocks and exit." so you can see if your host blocks are matching.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the config file like so:

```
ssh -F ~/.ssh/config
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two concepts.

Each config file definition is a matching pattern so, for example, your first one (default) will match one of the following:

- `ssh -T default`
- `ssh -T git@github.com`  (which will match the first pattern it finds, which is "default", and it will ignore the others)

The first one works because it's matching the declaration.  The second one works because the properties that you send to it match the key-value pairs inside of the declaration.

This is why the commands you are using don't work.

For example:  `ssh -T git@default`

This parses out as:

- User = git
- Hostname = default

If you go through your list of patterns, none of them match those key-value pairs.

This is also why you're getting `Could not resolve hostname: Name or service not known` - because the Hostname "default" does not exist (so it can't be resolved).

Just reference them by name... so:

```
ssh -T default
ssh -T work
ssh -T para
```

Per the docs:

> Host: Restricts the following declarations (up to the next Host or Match keyword) to be only for those hosts that match one of the patterns given *AFTER* the keyword. ...  The host is *USUALLY* the hostname argument given on the command line (see the CanonicalizeHostname keyword for exceptions).

Docs: https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#Host

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).